# Finding a substring within a string without using any built in functions

Tags: python-2.7

I have to find a particular substring within a string and its position within the string. This is very easy but I have to this without using any built in functions or methods in python. I would really appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks

```
string="ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAATTACAGACCTGAA"
```

substring='ttg'

Answer (score 1):

This code will work if you don't want to use any inbuilt function.

```
man = "ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCC$
check = "TTG"

for i in range (0, len(man)):
    if man[i]==check[0]:
            sum =0
            for j in range(0, len(check)):
                    if man[i+j] != check[j]:
                            break
                            sum = 0
                    else:
                            sum = sum +1
                            if sum == len(check):
                                print i
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to implement this without any builtin, as you need either `len` or `enumerate` to iterate with knowledge of the current index.

Although, here is an implementation with `len` only.

```
def find(s, sub):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(s):
        if s[i:len(sub)] == sub:
            return idx
    return -1
```

If you really want no builtin at all, here is a trick you could use.

```
def find(s, sub):
    sub_len = 0
    for _ in sub:
        sub_len += 1

    idx = 0
    while s[idx:idx+1]:
        if s[i:sub_len] == sub:
            return idx
    return -1
```

Of course this is somewhat cheating since iteration and slicing does more for you than many builtins.

Answer (score -1):

if you only want substring from your string you can use this:

```
str[12:15]
```

another examples:

```
a = '1234567890'
then 
>>> a[-3:-1]
'89'
>>> a[-3:]
'890'
>>> a[-2]
'9'
>>> a[5]
'6'
```